# Is there a way to have a highlighted chart as well as have interactivity of selecting elements in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, gghighlight

I have come across a beautiful chart on this webpage: https://ourworldindata.org/coronavirus and interested to know if we can build the same chart in R with **functionality of** having **highlighted series** as well as **selecting any line on hovering** ?

I have build **static highlighted charts** using `gghighlight` but those are **not interactive**.
`Plotly` can help in **interaction** but I think they don't work with `gghighlight`.

**So how can we have the combination of both `highlight and interactivity` in charts as in the link shared on top** ?

Is it possible to achieve same results in R ? It would be really helpful if someone could share an example or link that can help.

(**UPDATE**: May be I can manually highlight lines by creating a factor column instead of using `gghighlight` and then pass it to `ggplotly` but then can `ggplotly` or some other library provide similar results on hover ?)

(NOTE: Not looking for animation. Just need highlighted, hover over interactive chart)

Below is the snapshot of same chart *hovered over US* (This chart is also similar to the one shared in World Economic Forum many times.)

[image]

Comment: Does it have to be ggplot? If not highcharter or dygraphs might be useful. I've had success with dygraphs in the past. Also, you might want to try ggplot + ggvis

Comment: @J.Doe. Anything compatible with R is fine. It doesn't necessarily has to be `ggplot` or `plotly` or `gghighlight`. I have seen examples of `highcharter` and `dygraphs` I doubt if they will be that helpful but I will check those in detail now. `ggvis` looks interesting, and I didn't know we can get control wdgets(not sure) in R documents without shiny.

Comment: https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-series-highlighting.html

Comment: yes I think this will work. Thanks @J.Doe. for sharing this link. I will try using these examples !!!

Comment: It's also straightforward to do this with `plot_ly` / `ggplotly` - there is no need to switch the library (see below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `plotly` you can use `highlight()` to achive this.

This is a slightly modified example from [here](https://plotly-r.com/client-side-linking.html):

```
library(plotly)

# load the `txhousing` dataset
data(txhousing, package = "ggplot2")

# declare `city` as the SQL 'query by' column
tx <- highlight_key(txhousing, ~city)

# initiate a plotly object
base <- plot_ly(tx, color = I("black")) %>% 
  group_by(city)

# create a time series of median house price
time_series <- base %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  add_lines(x = ~date, y = ~median)

highlight(
  time_series, 
  on = "plotly_hover",
  selectize = FALSE, 
  dynamic = FALSE,
  color = "red",
  persistent = FALSE
)
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for sharing the example @ismirsehregal. This will work well in what I need to achieve. Thanks again !!